# What metadata can I safely delete without affecting the appearance of an image?

Tags: metadata, exiftool

I would like to remove as much metadata as possible from an image without changing its appearance.

I have used `exiftool -all= image.jpg` and it works well most of the time, but quite often the colors come out different.

So instead I used `exiftool -all= image.jpg -tagsFromFile @ -TAGNAME` to avoid removing certain tags like "ColorSpace". Is there a list somewhere of tags that affect appearance in any way? If there isn't, any tips on how I could compile such as list?  Any tags that affect appearance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without color space information, images should be rendered using the sRGB profile.  To preserve the color space information, you should preserve the ColorSpace, InteropIndex and ICC_Profile tags.

Comment: Preserving these three tags works on all the examples I have gathered. By the way, thank you for ExifTool, it's a lifesaver.

Comment: Thank you: `exiftool -all= image.jpg -tagsfromfile @ -colorspace -interopindex -icc_profile` seems to work.